# is my harddisk fully formated during Ubuntu installation?

Tags: installation, dual-boot

Last night i installed ubuntu on my laptop which earlier had windows 7. For installation i made one 26GB partition free and install ubuntu on it.During installation i choose "something else" optin and select the drive which i earlier free. But after completion of installation i didnt see option to choose between Win7 and ubuntu , it directly take me to ubuntu desktop and also i cant see my other windows partition in there. What should i do now to get those partition and since it is not detecting my Micromax net connector am not able to connect to the internet..

Comment: Please add a pastebin link to the result of the [bootinfoscript](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/) so we can see what the situation is. Thanks

Comment: PS also stop booting from and mounting the hard drive. Use the Ubuntu DVD/USB you installed from to boot in live CD mode ("Try Ubuntu"). Otherwise you run the risk of overwriting data.

Comment: To boot a live OS from USB you need to change the boot order in BIOS from the internal hard drive to USB drive.